# Android Status Bar Notification: make it un-clearable and have it return to app (not start a new instance)

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I am developing an Android app and I want a status bar notification that cannot be cleared by the user. Does anyone know how to do that? I've seen them with apps like Skimble where a non-clearable notification appears while using the application.

Also, I'd when the user clicks/presses the notification, I want it to return to the app instance that is already running. Right now it starts a new instance. Again like the Skimble app, I just want to return to the already running instance of the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I used FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT to make the notification persist. Here's the code:

```
  String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.mypic;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Title Text";
    CharSequence contentText = "Content text.";

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class); 
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"); 
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0); 

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    final int HELLO_ID = 1;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Instead of using the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` you can also use the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`, depending on where you want the notification to appear (more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR))

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution for the `NotificationCompat.Builder`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("MyApp")
        .setContentText("MyMsg")
        .setOngoing(true);
```

More at the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html).

Answer (score 0):

notification.setLatestEventInfo is deprecated so you have to use the Notification.builder and if your using 2.X and lower API you have to use NotificationComacpt.Builder and this is not applicable and I couldn't make my notification stays. so I used setDeleteIntent and pointed to the same activity and on resume method just call the block of code which shows your notification. So it is kinda work around.