# How to make an Android app running all the time

Tags: android

I am makin an android application on Emergency communication.I want my application should run all the time and whenever it needs it should be able to run.I want that user should not be able to close it by any means.Like Google Maps application which is restarted again on killing its all activities and even we force close it,it will be restarted.

Comment: Read about services [service reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are learning app development ... but this is not the way you should pose question here... you should post what you have done and code issues and not ask for an entire class...

But i will try to answer your question are you trying to create an app which when started wont be able to be closed and come back to home screen ???!!!!!

See you are creating an app which will run on android operating system which is similar to linux so you must follow the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) 
[LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

I remember i created an app where there were shortcuts on screen so using that i was directing the user to specific links but you can use for calling etc.. i donno if that is what you are searching for...

You might create a [notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866265/android-status-bar-notification-make-it-un-clearable-and-have-it-return-to-app) bar if you want which cannot be cancelled  and you can place the code in the intent which will be called from this...

Also services are there which u can utilized what other users have suggested...

thx

Comment: I tried to Force close Google Map.But when I did it,it restarted automatically,I want my app to work this way,Because its an Emergency system like if somebody even touch my phone after the screen is on,it should be able to send a message to the number I wanted.App should work all the time in background,even if user try to close it.

Comment: i donno where you have that when you close google map it restarts mine does not happen i m using nexus s vanila android ... anyways if you go thru the activity lifecycle you will see there is destroy method and pause try to start your activity in onpause and ondestroy i hope it will never close... just try once not sure but logically it will work... but still i think its bad maybe the notification will do wat you want without disturbing the user.... let see...

thx

Answer (score -1):

You could use an extra service running in the foreground, but there will be always a notification of this service in the notification bar.

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground